# horizontal scrolling div onclick with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, onclick

I have spent the last two days looking for a simple javascript or jquery code for this.  I want to incorporate a horizontal scrolling div using javascript or jquery to display images and descriptive text for the work page of my web portfolio.

It would function very similar to the glide-onclick scrolling shown here: http://www.dyn-web.com/code/scroll/demos.php#horiz Unfortunately that code license is $40, and I am a broke student.

On loading of the page, three portfolio images will be shown. Extras are hidden in the overflow to the right. Onclick of a left arrow (I can create), a new image slide comes into view from the right. A right arrow click sends it back into overflow. I don't want scrollbars, just arrows controlling the slides.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: srsly?! $40 for that functionality?  Let me see if I can throw an example together... is that in a div or does the slideshow take up the whole page?

Comment: You can still view the js file without paying you know.

Comment: @kei correct... to learn from it... but actually using it would be theft...

Comment: There would be a div containing all images within the main content div of the page. Each image will probably be in its own div as well, so I can style it with descriptive text and a link. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use code like this:

```
function FixMargin(left) {
    $(this).css("left", left);
}

$(document).ready(function () {

$('#rightbutton').click(function () {
    var left = parseInt($("#bitToSlide").css('left'), 10);
    $("#bitToSlide").animate({ left: left - pageWidth }, 400, FixMargin(left - pageWidth));
});

$('#leftbutton').click(function () {
    var left = parseInt($("#bitToSlide").css('left'), 10);
    $("#bitToSlide").animate({ left: left + pageWidth }, 400, FixMargin(left + pageWidth));
});

}
```

where your html looks like this:

```
<div id="slideleft" class="slide">
    <div class="inner" id="bitToSlide" style="width:1842px">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr valign="top">
                <td id="page1" style="width: 614px">
                </td>

                <td id="page2" style="width: 614px">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and your css looks like this:

```
.slide
{
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
height:365px;
width:597px;
margin:1em 0;
background-color:#E9ECEF;
border:0px
}

.slide .inner
{
position:absolute;
left:0;
bottom:0;
height:365px;
padding:0px;
background-color:#E9ECEF;
color:#333
}
```

I wrote the above a really long time ago - so you probably want to update it a bit (replace the table's with div's for example) but it works.

You obviously need the two buttons on there as well

Comment: I have this close to working, but in dreamweaver your javascript code is generating an error (red box appears at end of the code). Any idea why? I have it wrapped in 

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of jQuery plugins which allow you to do this very easily.
For ex: http://slidesjs.com/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that input, but I've tried jquery sliders similar to what you posted and it's not quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Not tested code but just giving you a hint.

```
<div id="imageContainer">
  <div id="imageWrapper">
    <img />
    <img />
  </div>
  <span id="left">Left</span>
  <span id="right">right</span>
</div>

var imageWidth = 200;
$("#left").click(function(){
  $("#imageWrapper").animate({marginLeft:"-="+imageWidth}, 500);
  //Offcourse you need to handle the corner cases when there is not image to move left
});

$("#right").click(function(){
  $("#imageWrapper").animate({marginLeft:"+="+imageWidth}, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to iscroll 4.

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

You have a scrollTo method or scrollToElement method...